# Can a were-creature druid Wild Shape when in hybrid form?

Tags: dnd-4e, druid, wild-shape, theme

Does were-creature's level 10 hybrid form count as "humanoid" for the wording of Wild Shape?

- A Wererat/bear/wolf's level 10 feature says "When you use the [animal] shape power, you can assume the form of a humanoid-[animal] hybrid instead..."
- Wild Shape says "You change from your humanoid form to beast form..."

So what I'm asking is, can you Wild Shape from the were-creature's hybrid form to another beast form?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to in the first place when you can use both Beast Form and non-Beast Form powers in hybrid mode?

Comment: Mainly for the shifting effects that Agile Form/Pouncing Form give when you Wild Shape from humanoid form to beast form.

Answer (score 1):

In the monster manual, lycanths are considered humanoids who can use the change shape to swap to a [whatever animal].

The combat tactics refer to the "natural hybrid form" i.e. the form presented in the template with the stats, abilities, etc.  This form is considered to be a humanoid.  Thus, since Wild Shape allows you to change from humanoid to beast, you can.

Still not convinced?

The Monster Manual defines Humanoid as:

"Humanoid monsters are usually bipedal, but some have monstrous or animalistic characteristics, such as the squidlike head of a mind flayer or the serpentine body of a yuan-ti abomination"

Clearly, that fits a hybrid were-creature.

So in conclusion, Since a were-creature is considered "humanoid" by the monster manual, then a Druid can switch to beast for using Wild Shape